# Default routing change ASP .Net 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a project ASP .NET 5 MVC 6. In that I want to change default routing. So in StartUp.cs file I have changed the controller and action name. But it is redirecting to old route instead new one. Below is code for old and new default routes.

Old default route

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {  
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
}
```

New (change is only of controller and action name) route

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {  
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" });
            });
}
```

Help to solve this issue. I want to redirect to my another controller-action method. Project is of ASP .NET 5 MVC 6 and login controller is of 'MVC controller class' type.

Thank You.

Comment: do you have a LoginController ?

Comment: Yes. public class LoginController : Controller

Answer (score 5):

Try to use

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            })
```

;

Comment: I have tried it. But url attribute is not supported in ASP .NET 5 MVC 6

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core (former ASP.NET 5) you can set the default route in the "launchSettings.json" file.  You will find it in your project's Properties.

Comment: launch URL and default route are different things

Comment: @NikaGamkrelidze I thought that's what he was asking